# how can i know how a task finished when using java's Future class

Tags: java, runnable, future

I'm using the java's Future class to execute a task, but the method isDone returns true if the task completed. Completion may be due to normal termination, an exception, or cancellation -- in all of these cases, this method will return true.

is there a way to know if it ended because an exception or because it finished successfully ?

Answer (score 6):

When you call Future.get() method, there is 4 possible outcomes:

- You get the result value
- You get CancellationException - if the computation was cancelled (e.g. Future.cancel(true) is called)
- You get ExecutionException - if the computation threw an exception
- You get InterruptedException - if the current thread was interrupted while waiting (e.g. executor.shutdownNow() is called)

Comment: How do we find out if a Runnable or Callable is being executed by a thread? Does Future provide that information?

Answer (score 2):

You could simply try to retrieve the value - the `get` method then either throws an exception, or returns the value.

Answer (score 0):

I have used it in my code and the only way you can figure out if the task really completed successfully is by using get()